# How do we select a column that is not in a group by clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do we select a column that is not in a `GROUP BY` clause?

When executing the below code I get the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T012.hr_empl_code
    ,T012.hr_taxs_code
    ,max(T012.hr_efec_dati) AS last_hr_efec_dati
FROM hrtempnm T000
INNER JOIN hrtemptx T012 ON T000.hr_empl_code = T012.hr_empl_code
WHERE T000.hr_stus_code LIKE 'e%'
    AND T000.hr_stus_code <> 'epla'
    AND T000.hr_efec_dati = max(T000.hr_efec_dati)
GROUP BY T012.hr_empl_code
    ,T000.hr_efec_dati
    ,T012.hr_taxs_code
HAVING T000.hr_efec_dati = max(T000.hr_efec_dati)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: My question is what are you trying to do???

Comment: I am trying to select a table column that is not in the group by clause

Comment: If you want to select a column that is not in the GROUP BY clause, you must use a function like MIN or MAX, to specify which value you want. If you want all the values, you must include that column in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Are you able to put example data and specify which column you would like to include in your select?

Comment: You don't need distinct and group by.  Well do you have and aggregate in the where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies on your `WHERE` clause, on the 3rd condition:

```
AND T000.hr_efec_dati = max(T000.hr_efec_dati)
```

In here you are referencing the aggregate function `MAX`. The `WHERE` clause filters data before starting any grouping, so you can't use aggregate functions in here, that's what the `HAVING` clause is for.

Remove that condition from the `WHERE` clause and it will work (you already have it on the `HAVING` clause).

For your question, there are only 2 ways of selecting a column not being mentioned in a `GROUP BY`:

- It's an aggregate function like `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG` (or a custom one).
- It's a constant value (hard-coded or @variable), or an expression that returns a constant value and does not reference any column not grouped by.

If you want to see column values for a particular group or groups, you should use the result of the grouping set and join them again with your table through the grouped by columns. Like this:

```
;WITH GroupedValues AS
(
    SELECT -- Remove the DISTINCT if you are already grouping by the same columns
        T012.hr_empl_code
        ,T012.hr_taxs_code
        ,max(T012.hr_efec_dati) AS last_hr_efec_dati
    FROM hrtempnm T000
    INNER JOIN hrtemptx T012 ON T000.hr_empl_code = T012.hr_empl_code
    WHERE T000.hr_stus_code LIKE 'e%'
        AND T000.hr_stus_code <> 'epla'
    GROUP BY T012.hr_empl_code
        ,T000.hr_efec_dati
        ,T012.hr_taxs_code
    HAVING T000.hr_efec_dati = max(T000.hr_efec_dati)
    -- remove the ORDER BY when used in a subquery (without TOP)
)
SELECT
    T012.hr_empl_code,
    T012.hr_taxs_code,

    UnGroupedColumn1,
    UnGroupedColumn2

FROM
    hrtempnm T000
    INNER JOIN hrtemptx T012 ON T000.hr_empl_code = T012.hr_empl_code
    INNER JOIN GroupedValues AS G ON 
        T012.hr_empl_code = G.hr_empl_code AND
        T012.hr_taxs_code = G.hr_taxs_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it ..

```
WITH sequenced_data as 
(
select DISTINCT
    T000.hr_empl_code, 
    T012.hr_taxs_code, T012.hr_efec_dati,
    Rank() over (Partition BY T000.hr_empl_code order by T012.hr_efec_dati  DESC) as Rankx
    --,T012.hr_efec_dati
FROM 
    hrtempnm T000, 
    hrtemptx T012
WHERE   
    T000.hr_empl_code = T012.hr_empl_code
AND T000.hr_stus_code LIKE 'e%' AND T000.hr_stus_code <> 'epla'
) 

SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  Rankx = 1
```